# Exception on OnPressed function while using animateTo function In TabbarView

Tags: flutter, tabcontrol, tabbar

I am Trying to write a code for my project which uses a TabBarView with 4 tabs and has a Global Key so that I can Use the Tab controller anywhere in the app,
however when I tried to Call the animateTo Function using an onpressed Function of Raised Button It Keeps Throwing Errors as follows:

Have Already Done This://Tried Creating a function in the same file as the controller to change the view

```
class MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  static final homePageKey=GlobalKey<MyTabsState>();
  TabController tabcontroller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabcontroller = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 4);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    tabcontroller.dispose();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: homePageKey,
      bottomNavigationBar: new Material(
          color: mainUiColor,
          child: new TabBar(
              controller: tabcontroller,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              labelColor: Colors.redAccent,
              tabs: <Tab>[
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.home)),
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.photo_album)),
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite)),
              ])),
      body: new TabBarView(controller: tabcontroller, children: <Widget>[
        new First(),
        new PhotoGallery(),
        new Third(),
        new SocialMedia(),
      ]),

    );
  }
  void changePage(){

     tabcontroller.animateTo(2);
  }
}
```

```
I/flutter ( 4993): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter ( 4993): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture: I/flutter ( 4993): The method 'changePage' was called on null. I/flutter ( 4993): Receiver: null I/flutter ( 4993): Tried calling: changePage() I/flutter ( 4993): I/flutter ( 4993): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: I/flutter ( 4993): #0    Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5) I/flutter ( 4993): #1      _PhotoGalleryState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:myproject/screenTabs/SecondTab.dart:97:52) I/flutter ( 4993):
#2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:511:14) I/flutter ( 4993):
#3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:566:30) I/flutter ( 4993):
#4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:166:24) I/flutter ( 4993): #5      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:240:9) I/flutter ( 4993): #6    TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:211:7) I/flutter ( 4993): #7    GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27) I/flutter ( 4993): #8
_WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:225:20) I/flutter ( 4993):
#9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:199:22) I/flutter ( 4993):
#10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7) I/flutter ( 4993):
#11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7) I/flutter ( 4993):
#12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7) I/flutter ( 4993):
#16     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:233:10) I/flutter ( 4993): #17     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:5) I/flutter ( 4993): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async) I/flutter ( 4993): I/flutter ( 4993): Handler: onTap I/flutter ( 4993): Recognizer: I/flutter ( 4993):   TapGestureRecognizer#bfc40(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: ready, won arena, finalPosition: I/flutter ( 4993):   Offset(126.9, 667.6), sent tap down)
```

Comment: Whre are you calling `changePage`?

Comment: In a drawer using a button/ListTile

Answer (score 0):

If I were a betting man I'd bet you may be trying to call changePage() on one of the pages listed in your tabBarView. A global key doesn't really make the item available anywhere in the app, you'd have to store it somewhere higher up in the widget tree using an inherited widget or pass it down to its children as a property in order to actually use it. It looks like something you may want to consider looking into is a [CupertinoTabScaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabScaffold-class.html). Then you could wrap that around the main views, and work with it there and have it show up across the entire app. This might be a bit easier than using the current setup.

Comment: I was calling changepage in another file in a Raised Button / List Tile , But I end getting error has the Getter changepage was called in null

Comment: Let me amend my statement, you can't use the global key anywhere you don't have it passed to as a property. Not just pages, but anywhere.

Comment: This is why it's resulting as null. According to that widget, the key doesn't exist. It has no way to reference that specific object and thus, can't use its functions (such as changePage). I still recommend looking into the cupertino widget I mentioned above. This will give you the results I think you're looking to achieve.

Comment: Will surely look into it and get back

Comment: But I Do have A reference to the Current state like the way global key is used Class name.globalKey.currentState.changepage()

Comment: This is not the proper way to call something throughout the app. The key may be called global but it's placed inside of the MyTabsState class. Meaning it's only going to work within that class. Want to use something outside of a class then it needs to be declared outside of that class. Though that's definitely not the way to do this. The proper way to reference something throughout an app is using something like an inherited widget or something in that vein.